# Gradle android test plugin doesn't find tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to set up unit testing using Android Studio, Gradle and Jake Wharton's `gradle-android-test-plugin`.

But when I run `$ ./gradlew test`, test results get generated in `build/test-report`, but they show that no tests were found.

Do I need to configure the location of the test source?

The project is structured like so

```
MyProject
    build
    libs
    src        
        main
            java
                com
                    myproject
                        MainActivity.java
            res
        test
            java
               com
                   myproject
                      DemoTest.java
                      RobolectricGradleTestRunner.java
```

When I run `$ ./gradlew test --info` to get more info, I notice the following in the output.  Could this be a clue to why the tests aren't being found?

```
:MyProject:testDebug 
file or directory '[...]/MyProject/build/test-classes/debug', not found 
Skipping task ':MyProject:testDebug' as it is up-to-date (took 0.508 secs).
```

Here's the `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
        classpath 'com.squareup.gradle:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.9.1-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-test'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs/main', include: '*.jar')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.1.+'
    testCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

add

```
sourceSets {
    instrumentTest.setRoot('src/test')
}
```

in `android { ... }`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it, but I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: I wasted a lot of time yesterday because of this issue. I wish I remember how exactly I fixed it.. Did you try `./gradlew clean`?

Comment: try calling it androidTest instead of instrumentTest